# error with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am trying to use the rails nested resources in ajax but I get this error: Processing by ListapromoController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "detalleprom"=>{"Articulo"=>"2", "listaprom_id"=>"1247", "PromoId"=>"1247", "Id"=>"1247"}, "commit"=>"Create Detalleprom", "listaprom_id"=>"1245"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: listaprom):
  app/controllers/listapromo_controller.rb:81:in `listaprom_params'
  app/controllers/listapromo_controller.rb:31:in`create'

this is my index view:

```
 <!--<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>-->
<h1>Lista de listapromo</h1>
<style>
.container {
}

</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mynewlistaprom">
        Nuevo listaprom
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>



  <table id="listapromo" class="display"><!--el id listapromo es de datatables referenciado en listapromo.coffe y display class es una clase de datatables-->
  <thead>

    <tr><!--active es para sombrear la fila-->
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Caduca</th>
      <th>Inicio</th>
      <th>Final</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody id="container_listapromo">
      <%= render @listapromo %><!--carga todos los listapromo-->
</tbody>


</table>
<!-- Modal create action -->
<%= form_for(@listaprom, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %> <!--ajax remote: true-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="mynewlistaprom" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar listaprom</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :Lista, "Clave:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <%= f.text_field :Lista, class: "form-control listaprom_clave" %>
            </div>

              <%= f.label :Caduca,"Caduca:", class: "control-label col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-1"%>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <%= f.check_box :Caduca %>
              </div>

            <%= f.label :Activa,"Inactiva:", class: "control-label col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-1"%>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <%= f.check_box :Activa %>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :Descripcion,"Descripción:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <%= f.text_field :Descripcion, class: "form-control listaprom_descripcion" %>
            </div>
            <%= f.label :Tipo, "Tipo:", class: "control-label col-md-1"  %>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <%= f.select :Tipo, ['Producto','Monto de Venta','Volumen'], class: "form-control"%>

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="well center-block">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :FechaI,"Inicio:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <%= f.text_field :FechaI, class: "form-control datepicker listaprom_fechainicio" %>
              </div>

              <%= f.label :FechaF,"Fin:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <%= f.text_field :FechaF, class: "form-control datepicker listaprom_fechafinal" %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <%= f.hidden_field :IdEmpresa, value: current_usuario.empresa_id %>


        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mynewlistapromclose">Close</button>
          <%= submit_tag "Create", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<%end%>
</div>
```

my partial _listaprom.html.erb

```
<tr id="listaprom_<%= listaprom.id %>">
  <td><%=listaprom.id%></td>
  <td><%=listaprom.Descripcion%></td>
  <td><%=listaprom.Caduca%></td>
  <td><%=listaprom.FechaI%></td>
  <td><%=listaprom.FechaF%></td>
  <td><%=listaprom.Activa%></td>





    <td>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myupdatelistaprom_<%= listaprom.id %>">
          Edit
        </button>
        <!--Destroy-->
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', listaprom, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs", remote:true %>



      </td>


<td class="no" >
      <!--Modal - update listaprom-->
    <div nohidden class="modal fade si" id="myupdatelistaprom_<%= listaprom.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar listaprom</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= form_for(listaprom, :method => :put, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %><!--ajax-->

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :Lista, "Clave:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <%= f.text_field :Lista, class: "form-control listaprom_clave" %>
              </div>

                <%= f.label :Caduca,"Caduca:", class: "control-label col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-1"%>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                  <%= f.check_box :Caduca %>
                </div>

              <%= f.label :Activa,"Inactiva:", class: "control-label col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-1"%>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <%= f.check_box :Activa %>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :Descripcion,"Descripción:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <%= f.text_field :Descripcion, class: "form-control listaprom_descripcion" %>
              </div>
              <%= f.label :Tipo, "Tipo:", class: "control-label col-md-1"  %>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <%= f.select :Tipo, ['Producto','Monto de Venta','Volumen'], class: "form-control"%>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="well center-block">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :FechaI,"Inicio:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <%= f.text_field :FechaI, class: "form-control datepicker listaprom_fechainicio" %>
                </div>

                <%= f.label :FechaF,"Fin:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <%= f.text_field :FechaF, class: "form-control datepicker listaprom_fechafinal" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="myupdatebutton_<%= listaprom.id %>" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
            </div>
            <%end%>

            <%= form_for([@listaprom,@detalleprom],:url => {:listaprom_id => 1245},  remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |d| %> <!--ajax remote: true-->
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= d.label :Articulo, "Articulo:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                  <%= d.text_field :Articulo, class: "form-control listaprom_clave" %>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                </div>
                <%= d.hidden_field :listaprom_id, value: listaprom.id %>
                <%= d.hidden_field :PromoId, value: listaprom.id %>
                <%= d.hidden_field :Id, value: listaprom.id %>

                <%= d.submit %>
              </div>

            <%end%>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

my model detalleprom.rb

```
class Detalleprom < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'Id'
  belongs_to :listaprom, class_name:"Listaprom", foreign_key: "PromoId"
end
```

my model listaprom.rb

```
class Listaprom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :detallepromo, class_name: "Detalleprom", foreign_key: "PromoId"
end
```

my detallepromo controller

```
class DetallepromoController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_detalleprom, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_listaprom

  # GET /detallepromo
  # GET /detallepromo.json
  def index
    @detallepromo = Detalleprom.all
  end

  # GET /detallepromo/1
  # GET /detallepromo/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /detallepromo/new
  def new
    @detalleprom = Detalleprom.new
  end

  # GET /detallepromo/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /detallepromo
  # POST /detallepromo.json
  def create
    @detalleprom = Detalleprom.new(detalleprom_params)
    @detalleprom.listaprom = @listaprom

    respond_to do |format|
      if @detalleprom.save
        format.html { redirect_to @detalleprom.listaprom, notice: 'Detalleprom was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @detalleprom }
        format.js #ajax
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @detalleprom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js #ajax
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /detallepromo/1
  # PATCH/PUT /detallepromo/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @detalleprom.update(detalleprom_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @detalleprom.listaprom, notice: 'Detalleprom was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @detalleprom }
        format.js #ajax
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @detalleprom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js #ajax
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /detallepromo/1
  # DELETE /detallepromo/1.json
  def destroy
    @detalleprom.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to detallepromo_url, notice: 'Detalleprom was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js #ajax
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listaprom
      @listaprom = Listaprom.find(params[:listaprom_id])
    end

    def set_detalleprom
      @detalleprom = Detalleprom.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def detalleprom_params
      params.require(:detalleprom).permit(:Articulo, :listaprom_id, :PromoId, :Cantidad, :Tipo, :TipoProm, :Monto, :Volumen, :TipMed, :IdEmpresa, :Nivel)
    end
end
```

my listapromo controller

```
class ListapromoController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listaprom, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listapromo
  # GET /listapromo.json
  def index
    @listapromo = Listaprom.all
    @listaprom = Listaprom.new
    @detalleprom = Detalleprom.new
  end

  # GET /listapromo/1
  # GET /listapromo/1.json
  def show
    @detalleprom = Detalleprom.new
  end

  # GET /listapromo/new
  def new
    @listaprom = Listaprom.new
  end

  # GET /listapromo/1/edit
  def edit
    @detalleprom = Detalleprom.new
  end

  # POST /listapromo
  # POST /listapromo.json
  def create
    @listaprom = Listaprom.new(listaprom_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listaprom.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listaprom, notice: 'Listaprom was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listaprom }
        format.js #ajax
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @listaprom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js #ajax
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listapromo/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listapromo/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listaprom.update(listaprom_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listaprom, notice: 'Listaprom was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listaprom }
        format.js #ajax
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @listaprom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js #ajax
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listapromo/1
  # DELETE /listapromo/1.json
  def destroy
    @listaprom.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listapromo_url, notice: 'Listaprom was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js #ajax
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listaprom
      @listaprom = Listaprom.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listaprom_params
      params.require(:listaprom).permit(:Lista,:listaprom_id, :Descripcion, :Caduca, :FechaI, :FechaF, :Grupo, :Activa, :Tipo, :IdEmpresa)
    end
end
```

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :listapromo do
    resources :detallepromo
  end
```

Comment: sounds like you have to pass the variable through locals: {       } to `_listaprom.html.erb` ... see this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Comment: thanks for answer @Timmy  I tryed but its the same result:     locals: {listaprom_id: listapromo.ids} %>

Answer (score 0):

I assume you got the error when trying to submit this form:

```
<%= form_for([@listaprom,@detalleprom],:url => {:listaprom_id => 1245},  remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |d| %> <!--ajax remote: true-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= d.label :Articulo, "Articulo:", class: "control-label col-md-2" %>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <%= d.text_field :Articulo, class: "form-control listaprom_clave" %>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
            </div>
            <%= d.hidden_field :listaprom_id, value: listaprom.id %>
            <%= d.hidden_field :PromoId, value: listaprom.id %>
            <%= d.hidden_field :Id, value: listaprom.id %>

            <%= d.submit %>
          </div>

        <%end%>
```

If you're trying to update `listaprom` and its associated `detalleprom`, you can use `field_for` and add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to your `listaprom` model. Don't forget to modify your strong params too. The way you're doing it here sends a `Create Detalleprom` request to `ListapromoController`. The controller doesn't understand the request and thus the 400 code.

The following form will create a `detalleprom` associated with `@listaprom`

```
<%= form_for @listaprom, remote: true do |d| %>
(your code from @listaprom)
  <%= d.field_for :detalleprom do |dd| %>
    <%= dd.label :Articulo %>
    <%= dd.text_field :Articulo %>
   (rest of your code for detalleprom)
  <% end %>
<%end>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am trying to create a Detalleprom but this form is out of the listaprom edit form. I need to create a Detalleprom because listaprom has many Detalleprom and i need to add two or more in a existing listaprom creting a list.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to create a Datelleprom that belongs to a certain listaprom. That's the exact kind of situation where you should use field_for.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with this code can I create 2 or more detalleprom in the same listaprom?

Comment: I think you can create only one detalleprom at one time with the form. But you can submit it multiple times to create more objects. But I think maybe your code is OK, but you might want to remove `:url => {:listaprom_id =>1245}` from the form_for argument list. The create action should be sent to Detalleprom controller, not Listaprom controller. Having `[@listaprom, @detalleprom]` is enough to make sure the form will be able to find the correct @listaprom instance.

Comment: if I remove this line: ":url => {:listaprom_id => 1245}," I get this error: "No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"detallepromo", :listaprom_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:listaprom_id]".

Comment: I think maybe its because I create and edit in the same view? and its tell me: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: listaprom):  because in the listaprom controller  @listaprom = Listaprom.new ?

Comment: Yes the problem is you have @listaprom = Listaprom.new in the controller. Since you want to create a detalleprom associated with listaprom of id 1245, you should in your ListapromController#index change `@listaprom = Listaprom.new` to `@listaprom=Listaprom.find(1245)`.   The idea is that any instance variable you want to access from the view needs to be provided by the action.

Comment: thanks for the answer, 1245 was for testing, It should be :listaprom_id => <%= listaprom.id %>. If I change the Listaprom.new I won't be able to create a new Listaprom, there must be a way to do it but how?

Comment: You can't create a new listaprom and a new detalleprom associated with it in this form at the same time, because it is submitted to the detalleprom controller and the controller couldn't determine the id of the listaprom as it is not created yet. You'll somehow have to pass the listaprom id to the controller. That means you need to create a listaprom object first. Then you can pass its id to the create action. The easy way is to do the form on a Listprom#show page so you'll have the listaprom id from the params.